# I want to create new order in magento admin shipping method and payment method is not working

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, payment

When I try to create an order via the backend, under
payment method it showes "No Payment Information Required" and

Shipping Method showes "Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time."

But in the frontend it showes both of the method.

Did I miss some setting?

Answer (score 3):

(partial answer)

Magento does not allow all payment or shipping methods for orders by the backend. This makes sense, as for example, when you use PayPal and order via the backend, the user can/should not provide his credentials to login and pay with PayPal.

Payment methods have a flag `$_canUseInternal`, see for example in the file `app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Standard.php:39`

You could try to overwrite your payment method in `app/code/local` by copying the model file and set this flag to true. But there is no guarantee for it to work. If you use a 3rd party module for the payment, you should contact the extension vendor to fix this.

Concerning the shipping method I currently do not have an answer.

Comment: now i m using braintree paypal and its working automatically

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar problem at my company. We were selecting a product from the list to add to the order then clicking the shipping calculator without actually clicking the 'Add selected products to order' button at the top.  We overlooked the button and thought that the product that was checked was already assigned to the order. So, when we clicked submit order, nothing was actually added to the order yet. ergo, no shipping available.